# __doPostBack not firing in ie11 but firing in chrome

Tags: asp.net

my task is export div contents to image 
i am using this script

```
function ConvertToImage(btnExport) {
    html2canvas($("#<%=exportimage.ClientID %>")[0]).then(function (canvas) {
      var base64 = canvas.toDataURL();
      $("[id*=hfImageData]").val(base64);
      __doPostBack(btnExport.name, "");
    });
    return false;
}
```

__doPostBack not firing in ie11 but its working in chrome. plz suggest how can i fix postback in ie 11

Comment: Have you checked for any JS errors in the browser?

Comment: Is JavaScript enabled in IE11? In IE11, if you press F12, you will get the developer tools which should help you see any JS errors.

Comment: try this article: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IE10AndIE11AndWindows81AndDoPostBack.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I added the server to the “Tools -> Comparability View Settings” in the IE browser, and my links started working again