# __dopostback does not work with update panel in outlook built-in IE

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer, updatepanel, dopostback

Scenario:

I have a outlook web add-in and the back end is built by asp.net web form.
This is the app structure:

```
index.aspx
    -action.ascx
        -js file
```

Inside the action custom control I have this:

```
<asp:updatepanel id="up_AI" runat="server" updatemode="Conditional">
    <contenttemplate>
        <script>
            var controlId = '<%= save.UniqueID %>';
        </script>
        <asp:button id="save" runat="server" text="Save" onclick="save_Click" onclientclick="doSomething(controlId, 'arg'); return false;"/>
    </contenttemplate> 
</asp:updatepanel>
```

Here is the js function:

```
function doSomething(id,arg){
//something
__dopostback(id,arg)
}
```

So when `doSmething()` is done, it should trigger the `save_Click` event

This usually work for the first time, but if I keep on returning back to the view and click the button, it will eventually fail. Either throw me a bunch of js error or just fail to update the UI even the server event is hit. Seems to me the combination usage of `update-panel` and `__dopostback` is the culprit.

This only occurs in outlook built-in IE. The normal IE and other browser does not have this issue. I am using outlook desktop 2016.

One of the many js errors I got `Unable to get property 'PageRequestManager' of undefined or null reference`

I have tried 
[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36797822/dopostback-not-firing-in-ie11-but-firing-in-chrome)
and
[That](https://forums.asp.net/t/1958921.aspx?__dopostback%20not%20firing%20in%20ie11)

Comment: What do you mean about the "outlook built-in IE"?

Comment: @Dillion if you use a outlook web add-in in the desktop outlook client, that add-in is ran in the outlook built-in browser enviroment

Comment: Based on your description, I create  an outlook web add-in project and add a web application, it seems that everything works well on my side. So, please post more details code, so that we could test it on our side. Besides, it is better to post the error message.